# How to store public color var in UWP

Tags: c#, .net, colors, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have this file called Produtos.cs (Produtos = Products)

```
namespace LabApp4.Models
{
public class Produto
{
    public int Codigo { get; set; }
    public string Titulo { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public int Ano { get; set; }
    public string Letter { get; set; }
}
}
```

How can i implement some var that would store a color? I tried some examples here, but no sucess.

Comment: You need a *Color* or *Brush*? Also you just need to store this in variable, or serialize it later?

Comment: @Romasz I will use it, i'm doing something like a a catalog, and the background of some "icon" must have it's own color, so a color brush may be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of solutions to solve this, for example you can use properties defined like this:

```
// this can be serializable if needed
public string color;

// non-serializable
public SolidColorBrush ItemBrush
{
    get
    {
        return new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(byte.Parse(color.Substring(1, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber),
                                   byte.Parse(color.Substring(3, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber), byte.Parse(color.Substring(5, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber),
                                   byte.Parse(color.Substring(7, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)));
    }
    set { color = value.Color.ToString(); }
}
```